# Renaming while loop in package algorithm

Tags: algorithmicx

How do I rename the `While` loop using `algorithm` and `algpseudocode`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm*}
  \caption{bar baz}
   \label{alg:interesting}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \While{foo bar}
     \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm*}
\end{document}
```

It prints it out as

```
While foo bar do
end while
```

I would like to it come as

```
Until foo bar repeat

end while
```

How do I change only the first part of the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original definition of the while block in `algpseudocode.sty` is

```
\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}%
{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}%
```

you can then replace `\algorithmicwhile` with `\algorithmicuntil`, and `\algorithmicdo` with `\algorithmicrepeat`; a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]{\algorithmicuntil\ #1\ \algorithmicrepeat}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}%

\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm*}
  \caption{bar baz}
   \label{alg:interesting}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \While{foo bar}
     \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I only replaced the first occurrence of `\algorithmicwhile` as requested in the question; perhaps it would be better to change both.

Perhaps, as **egreg** has suggested in a comment, a better option would be to define a new `Until` block; here's how this could be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[UNTIL]{Until}{EndUntil}[1]{\algorithmicuntil\ #1\ \algorithmicrepeat}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicuntil}%

\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm*}
  \caption{bar baz}
   \label{alg:interesting}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \Until{foo bar}
     \EndUntil
    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm*}
\end{document}
```

[image]